# GDB and NS2: how to stop program at some Function call

Tags: c++, gdb, tcl, breakpoints, ns2

I am using gdb to debug NS-2 which is a simulator for network protocols. It takes an .tcl file as input and interpret it. [I think it is an interpreter.]

Some of the code is written in tcl (events and creation of network components) and some in C++ (especially Packet Formats,  Agents etc.).

I have created an Agent in C++ and i want to stop it at some function call so that i can see the stack trace and find which other classes have been called before it.

This is what i have done:

There was some error in one of my MyAgent::function and it was giving Segmentation Fault and gdb was stopping there automatically. I could then see the stack trace. I rectified the error.

Now when i run

```
   gdb ./ns
   b MyAgent::function()
   /*
   When i press TAB after writing "b MyA" it gives me all functions 
   of my class :). when i press enter after above command -- 
   it asks me "Breakpoint on future shared library load" and i say Yes. 
   I hope this is ok ??
   */
   r myfiles/myWireless.tcl
```

Now it runs and do not stop anywhere. :(

I am sure that this function is being called, because when that Segmentation fault was occuring, it was stopping at that function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a breakpoint in that function:

> (gdb) break MyAgent::function()

You must make sure to compile with whatever options are necessary to get debug symbols. On GCC, use the `-g` or `-ggdb` options.

Comment: I think it is same as "b MyAgent::function()". I did this one too. its not stopping.

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI have you compiled with debug symbols?

Comment: i am sorry but i do not know about debug symbols or optimized code. What should i do to the Makefile ?

Comment: Look for something like CFLAGS. There you will probably see -O2 or something similar. Replace that with -O0. This disables optimization (which interferes with debugging).

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI if you are using g++, then compile with `-g` for debug symbols, or even better, with `-ggdb`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668962/what-is-the-difference-between-gcc-ggdb-and-gcc-g)

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI just configure with `--enable-debug`

Answer (score 0):

You need the `-args` option to specify the `tcl` script that will be executed.

Run `gdb` like this:

```
gdb -args ./ns  path/to/tcl/script.tcl
```

To enable debug flag to c++ code, if have not done it already, re-configure your ns2 instalation with:

```
./configure --enable-debug     ;# plus any other flags you use for configuring
make clean
make -j 3                    ;# -j for faster compiling
make install                   ;# optional
```

You can also use the `--with-tcldebug=...`, for debugging tcl code (You need to install tcldebug first for this option)

Comment: `-j 100` causes one hundred compilers to start concurrently. This is similar to a fork bomb and can cause resource depletion! Always use `-j` wisely, I only use it up to the (number of cores available - 1), so for a quad-core machine, I only set it to `-j 3`

Comment: @ekarak I haven't encountered this problem on my machine (maybe my disk is too slow?). I updated the answer to use fewer parallel processes just in case though.