# gcc: what's the difference between "-g" and "-ggdb"?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, difference

I am working under linux, it seems to me that the effect of "-g" and "-ggdb" are no much difference. I only find using "-ggdb" will generate binary several bytes bigger.

So what's the core difference that gdb should have one "-g" option and another "-ggdb" option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between gcc -ggdb and gcc -g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668962/what-is-the-difference-between-gcc-ggdb-and-gcc-g)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiled program should be stored at some where, for the debuggers (GDB here) to look into it and follow.

This is technically called as **"Debugging data format"**.

Some universaslly accepted debugging data formats are (there are some more):

COFF - Common Object File Format - on UNIX like systems.

PE/COFF -  Portable Executable - pretty famous on windows, usually dotnet uses it.

DWARF - popular on UNIX like systems.

etc..

The GDB options you asked in your question are related to generating these debugging data formats.

Based on documenation the funcdamental difference is:
option "g" provides the debugging data in particular system's native format. 
option "-ggdb" is bit rich and expensive. provides the debugging data in most expressive format available.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to read this [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options), and this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668962/what-is-the-difference-between-gcc-ggdb-and-gcc-g).